# Information about masm32 libraries

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

Where can I find information about masm32 libraries? Namely, what functions they contain and their syntax. Already tried to google StdOut and StdIn, found only questions on the forums and a couple of examples.

Comment: Look for `masmlib.chm` in the `C:\masm32\help` folder.

Comment: @rancid_rot Are you looking for third party libraries to help you with your assemble language programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

masmlib.chm in the C:\masm32\help folder. ©rkhb